# limit after group of the result mysql

Tags: mysql

I have following the mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM tbltest WHERE DATE(posted_date) BETWEEN '20120414' AND '20130414' GROUP BY title  ORDER BY mostviewed DESC LIMIT 30
```

Problem:
It return only 19 rows where row of duplicate title is eliminated but I want to return 30 rows after grouping. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want 30 rows per group?

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT 30` - limits the result to a maximum of 30, but if you have less results according tot he filter you are using you get as much results as your query finds as long as less than 30.

If you wish more than 30 results you will need to change your filter, but only to get more results is non usual reason for changing a filter.

Comment: I think OP means to see `30 Unique results`

Comment: ya you are correct. I was banging my head why its returning only 19 rows but actually there's maximum 19 rows when I checked in my database. sorry for that.